# PHP session failed

Tags: php, mysql, session

> File1.php

Here my php session is getting failed. I can't use my session variable 'username'.

```
$count = mysqli_num_rows($authentification); 

    if ($count==1) {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username; 
        header("location: home.php");

        } 
        else {
                echo"<script language='javascript'> alert('entered information is not correct'); </script>";
                header("location:portal.php");

        }
```

Here it's another file where i continued my session

> file2.php

```
session_start();
$username=$_SESSION["username"];

if($_SESSION["username"]){
    echo $output = "<h2><div id='bonjour'>\t<p><b>Bonjour $username, nous sommes le ".date("d-m-Y").", il est <span id='heureH'>".date('H:i:s')."</span>.</b></p></div>\r\n</h2>";

}else{
    echo"Session failed";
}
```

when i see on the browser it shows "session failed". Can you please tell me what is missing. I am new beginner in php

Comment: What is in your $username variable?

Comment: Do you have `session_start();` on the page where you initially set the username?

Comment: put your session_start(); @ top of file

Comment: @kidz : yes i have session_start() in both file before i use the session variable "username"

Comment: @Naincy Gupta : in file1 or file2?

Comment: Do you have enabled errors and warnings? I'm thinking you'd might have som unintended output before starting sessions.

Comment: Please start the session at the top of the file.

Comment: @Repox: Yes it's enabled and displaying only in my localhost

Comment: @Lakhan : I have started my session_start() just after <?php .

Comment: start your session on top before if and set $username to a default values say $username = "rsr" and try to access it in file2.php check double quote and single quote also while registering value in session

Comment: Just try to user other name in place of "username" as session variable.

Comment: you got any value in file2.php

Comment: disabled suhosin (which is a module to harden PHP) by editing /etc/php.d/suhosin.ini and putting a ; in front of

extension=suhosin.so

Comment: Something is being sent to the browser first which is causing the headers to be sent. Check your code to make sure that there isn't even a single space before your PHP code.

Comment: ok thanks i wil lcheck it out

Answer (score 1):

Do not start your session in an if condition. Start it at the top of your file. If the `$count` is not 1, then you do not start your session.

NOTE: And add an `exit;` after the `header("location:portal.php");`, and before the `header("location:portal.php");` do not create output with `echo`

Comment: I have made the changes you wrote. But Still the same message is displaying. Anything else is missing?

Answer (score 0):

I've got this behaviour when working on Mac Os Safari  browser. I used this code to get it work:

```
$currentCookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();
session_set_cookie_params(86400,$currentCookieParams["path"], $currentCookieParams["domain"], 
true, // cookie_secure
true  // cookie_httponly
);
```

You have to put it *before* session_start();

86400 = 1 day session lifetime

Comment: Is there any good reason for configuring this in your application, and not in `php.ini`  globally?

Comment: @NicoHaase: No - there's no special reason. This is just a proof of concept. If this solutions works, the php.ini way surely will be better.

Answer (score 0):

Start your session at the very top of your file before writing any other code, like you did in the second example

```
session_start();
$count = mysqli_num_rows($authentification); 

    if ($count==1) {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username; 
        header("location: home.php");

        } 
        else {
                echo"<script language='javascript'> alert('entered information is not correct'); </script>";
                header("location:portal.php");

        }
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess the second `session_start()` in your second snippet is causing the $_SESSION array to be reset.